# recursively wget in specific folder

Tags: linux, command-line, wget, recursive

I'm trying to get files from HTTP using wget command.

I need every file in:

```
http://9.9.9.9/a/b/c/d/
```

which is not a directory.

I was trying it by:

```
-A log,html,tgz,zip,txt,css,js
```

In addition, from that point:

```
http://9.9.9.9/a/b/c/d/needed_folder/
```

I need recursively all the files there (inside it there are few sub folders)
I tried it by using:

```
-I /needed_folder
```

I was using the following command:

`wget -r -A log,html,tgz,zip,txt,css,js -I /needed_folder  -np -nH --cut-dirs=4 -R index.html http://9.9.9.9/a/b/c/d/needed_folder/some_files_needed/`

This retrieve only index.html.1 file
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways in which **the web is not like a filesystem**: URLs are not paths, even though they are often mapped to paths. And, in the general case, even if they do `wget` has no way of knowing which ones they are. To explain why your command in particular doesn't work:

- `-r` or `--recursive` means that `wget` will download the URLs you specify, **parse the markup to find links to other files,** and then download those, repeating by default five times (which could end up being billions of links if it follows links outside the site).
- `-A`/`--accept`, `-I`/`--include-directories=` and `-R`/`--reject` specify patterns to *filter* the set above.
- `-np`/`--no-parent` ensures that only URLs starting with the URLs you've given are downloaded.
- `-nH`/`--no-host-directories` puts files from all hosts in the same directory.
- `--cut-dirs=number` generalizes the above to not create multiple directories on the *local* storage when downloading files.